# Delete everything from Subfolders through Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have directories like:

> ```
> c:\Project\Current\stage1\somefiles and some folders
> c:\Project\Current\stage2\somefiles and some folders
> c:\Project\Current\stage3\somefiles and some folders
> c:\Project\Current\stage4\somefiles and some folders
> c:\Project\Current\stage5\somefiles and some folders
> .
> .
> .
> c:\Project\Current\stage500\somefiles and some folders
> ```

I want to create a batch file so that everything inside `stage1`, `stage2`,..., `stage500` will get deleted but not any of other folders so that I can still see the above directories but empty.

Can someone please help?

Comment: If you found your own solution that's great, but please post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: @Flexo, done it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and is very simple

```
for /d %%X in (c:\Project\Current*) Do (
for /D %%I in ("%%X\*") do rmdir /s/q "%%I"
del /F /q "%%X\*")
```

Thanks for everyone's help..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
CD c:\Project\Current /d
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a-d /s /b') do (
    del "%%f" /q /f
)
```

There are three important parts:

**`for /f "tokens=*" %%f`** means we are iterating over all lines that are generated by the following command and temporarily save each line in the variable `%%f` for each iteration.

**`dir /a-d /s /b`** is the core of the code. This will list all files inside `c:\Project\Current\` including all subfolders. `/a-d` means that directories will be ignored as we don't want them to be erased. `/s` means we are searching any subfolder. `/b` sets the output format to simple mode so that each line of the output will contain nothing but the full path to a file.

**`del "%%f" /q /f`** simply deletes the file which is stored in `%%f`. `/q` means "don't ask me if I'm sure, just erase it" and `/f` means that any file - even if it is marked as system file or as invisible or protected - will be deleted. Don't miss the quotation marks around `%%f` as otherwise paths containing spaces will cause trouble.

Comment: It is doing something weird, I have also added pause after it and in the command prompt log list comes up like: C:\WINDOWS\system32>DEL /S /F /Q C:\tmp1
The directory name C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_en_sql_server_2014
_standard_edition_with_service_pack_1_x86_dvd_6669994.zip\en_sql_server_2014_sta
ndard_edition_with_service_pack_1_x86_dvd_6669994\1033_ENU_LP\x86\Setup\sql2008s
upport\pfiles\sqlservr\100\keyfile\1033 is too long.

Comment: Sorry, as I am not an expert, there seems to be still some issue with it, it is not changing the directory (CD), I tried manually changing it and it works but in this batch file, system does not change the directory and come up with the same thing as last time. sorry for being a pain.

Comment: No, I have just used the one you suggested.

Comment: @MichealS, many thanks for your help, I got the solution for my problem: for /d %%X in (c:\Project\Current\*) Do (
for /D %%I in ("%%X\*") do rmdir /s/q "%%I"
del /F /q "%%X\*")